# How to uninstall XQuartz on Mountain Lion?

Tags: xquartz

The instructions [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X11-UsersFAQ) are a little dated, and no longer work on Mountain Lion:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/X11* /System/Library/Launch*/org.x.* /Applications/Utilities/X11.app /etc/*paths.d/X11
sudo pkgutil --forget com.apple.pkg.X11DocumentationLeo
sudo pkgutil --forget com.apple.pkg.X11User
sudo pkgutil --forget com.apple.pkg.X11SDKLeo
sudo pkgutil --forget org.x.X11.pkg
```

Comment: There's newer uninstall instructions further down the page, under the heading ["Uninstall (Snow Leopard or Later)"](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X11-UsersFAQ#UninstallSnowLeopardorLater)

Answer (score 1):

look what I found:
"You may try Wineskin, but everything that uses Wine can be coimplicated to get working...  As of Wineskin 2.5.6 you shouldn't need XQuartz installed at all for 10.8, as Wineskin has a custom version built in.

That said, if you ever want to use Crossover or some older Wineskin wrappers people share (like from paulthetall.com or portingteam.com), you really need to have XQuartz installed.

If you really want to get rid of XQuartz, it is NOT a self contained app, and hardly any of it is actually in the XQuartz.app bundle.  You can do it multiple ways, but I'll give you the safest

Open Terminal.app and type the following...

open /opt

this should open up a Finder window showing you the contents of your /opt folder which is normally hidden.  In it you'll see a X11 folder, which houses all of XQuartz.  Select that X11 folder and Trash it.  It'll ask for an admin password to trash it."